# why opening firefox on linux mint terminal gives an error

Tags: firefox, terminal, linux-mint

when I open Firefox from the terminal i get this message:
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
And blinking cursor right under it.

1. why?
2. How to exit and go back to home directory

Thank you!
ps: firefox open normally
linux mint 21.1 vera
thinkpad T430 I5
Firefox 122.0.1 64

Thanks for your time :)

tried quit() and exit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this good discussion here regarding the question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378056/ubuntu-20-04-3-problems-running-firefox-from-terminal

I'll quote some points from the answers there to answer your question:

1. Why do you get this error? It's because you don't have any other firefox windows launched
2. How to exit? There are several ways:

   1. Press `Ctrl+C` inside your console to terminate the process
   2. Open a new terminal window, and run the command `sudo ps -aux | grep -i "firefox"`, take the process ID of the first entry and `kill` it using the command `sudo kill -9 PROCESS_ID`
   3. You could use a tool such as `disown` or `nohup` to run the process in the background and keep using the same terminal window. You can learn more about the differences between these tools here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)